# Ajax, HJS e Mustache

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js, mustache.js

não gosto de escrever HTML no Ajax, tipo isso...

```
    var orderTemplate = "" +
"<li data-id='{{_id}}'" +
"<p><strong>Nome:</strong> <span class='noedit nome'>{{ nome }}</span>" +
"<input class='edit nome'> </p> "+
"<p><strong> Bebida: </strong><span class='noedit bebida'>{{ bebida }}</span>" +
"<input class='edit bebida'> </p> " +
"<button data-id='{{_id}}' class='remove'> X </button>" +
"<button class='editOrder noedit'> Editar </button>" +
"<button class='saveEdit edit'> Salvar </button>" +
"<button class='cancelEdit edit'> Cancelar </button>" +
"</li>";

function addOrder(order) {
    $orders.prepend(Mustache.render(orderTemplate, order));
}
```

Então pesquisei sobre a tag template do html, que importa para o ajax um html. Essa parte eu consegui fazer, porém não consigo trazer as variáveis {{nome}} e {{bebida}} para ser printada na tela. E com o código acima, dentro do ajax, as variáveis são printadas na tela. É o mesmo código, porém pelo template do html não funciona. Utilizo o Mustache | hjs para renderizar as views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde, faça da seguinte forma `<span class='noedit nome'>" + {{ nome }} +
 "</span>" +`.... você tem que retirar as variáveis de dentro da string e concatena-las na string....